# Как сделать корректную пагинацию с ГЕТ-параметрами?

Tags: pagination, laravel-8

Делаю на laravel 8 вывод данных с пагинацией. Все работает замечательно. У меня свой шаблон пагинации. Он прописан так:

```
{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate') }}
```

Однако, когда я произвожу на странице еще поиск данных по некоторым параметрам, то в пагинацию не попадают ГЕТ-параметры. Пробовал писать так и так:

```
{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate')->withQueryString(true) }}
```

Или так, в контроллере пишу следующее:

```
$houses = $Model->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());
```

а в макете вывожу пагинацию так:

```
{{ $houses->links('catalogs.paginate') }}
```

Ничего не помогает. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение сформировать ссылку из всех гет-параметров:

```
{{ $houses->appends($_GET)->links('catalogs.paginate') }}
```

или так:

```
{{ $houses->appends(request()->query())->links('catalogs.paginate') }}
```